# Insert into table where values have sub queries and return multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have two tables (`table_users` and `table_values`)

`table_users` have columns consisting of `id`(primary auto increment), `username`, `logitude`, `latitude`

`table_values` consist of columns `user_id` and `otherUser_id`. Neither are primary keys or unique or auto increment.

The purpose of `table_value` is to store all the user's id who have the same `logitude` and `latitude` as the logged in user. However I do not want to add the main user itself, only the ones who match his/her location values. Also I don't want to add the other users if they have already been added regardless of their location values.

So below lets use bob as an example. I want to query the table_users and insert all the users id that match bob's longitude and latitude into table_values but not bob himself.

```
Table_users 
id    username longitude latitude
1      bob      1          2
2      sam      1          2
3      fred     3          4
4      alex     1          2

Table_values
user_id     otherUserId
1              2
1              4
2              1
2              4
4              1
4              2
```

So at the moment I am able to add users who have the same location without adding the main user but I cannot add multiple rows into `table_values`. Also when I run the current mysql query I add duplicates which isn't what I want.

Here is my query so far

```
INSERT INTO `table_values` (`user_id`, `otherUser_id`) VALUES ((Select `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'bob'), (Select `id` FROM `users` where `longitude` = 'bobs logitude AND `latitude` = bobs latitude AND `username` != 'bob'))
```

The values bob, 12 and 3 are just examples. These will be based on which user it is. The values are being passed through a php post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `insert . . . select`, not `insert . . . values`.  The following inserts all pairs that are equivalent to "bob":

```
INSERT INTO `table_values` (`user_id`, `otherUser_id`)
     Select `id`
     FROM `users` u1 join
          `users` u2
          on u1.value_1 = u2.value_2
     WHERE u1.`username` = 'bob' and u2.username <> 'bob';
```

The following inserts them where they do not already exist:

```
INSERT INTO `table_values` (`user_id`, `otherUser_id`)
     Select u1.`id`, u2.id
     FROM `users` u1 join
          `users` u2
          on u1.value_1 = u2.value_2
     WHERE u1.`username` = 'bob' and u2.username <> 'bob' and
           not exists (select 1 from table_values where u1.id = user_id and u2.id = otherUser_id);
```

I'm not sure if you want to check them in a different order.

I'm not sure what "`value_1` = 12 AND `value_2` = 3" are for, given the nature of your problem.

Comment: I'm so sorry I read over my question and it didn't make sense to what I was actually asking. I have edited my question so hopefully it's a bit clearer now

Comment: yay i got it thanks. made some minor changes to your code. thank you so much